# What is the scope of a Transaction used in shared EntityManager contexts?

Tags: java, jpa, persistence

In JPA:
consider the following example, which uses a Container managed transaction scoped Entity manager.

```
public class ItemDAOImpl implements ItemDAO { 
    @PersistenceContext(unitName="ItemService") 
    EntityManager em; 

    LoggingService ls; 

    public void createItem(Item item) { 
        em.persist(item); 
        ls.log(item.getId(), "created item"); 
    } 

    // ... 
}  

public class LoggingService implements AuditService { 
    @PersistenceContext(unitName="ItemService") 
    EntityManager em; 
    
 
    public void log(int itemId, String action) { 
        // verify item id is valid 
        if (em.find(Item.class, itemId) == null) { 
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown item id"); 
        } 
        LogRecord lr = new LogRecord(itemId, action); 
        em.persist(lr); 
    } 

}
```

Am I right in supposing that `ls.log()` method
will use the transaction of the calling method.
I'm pretty confused about these things right now, can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are in EJBs, then very probably those methods will use the same transaction, because of the [default transaction propagation](http://www.byteslounge.com/tutorials/java-ee-ejb-transaction-propagation-transactionattribute-tutorial) method. Just check how they are configured, as it seems they are configured in an XML file.

Comment: what if they are classes used in EJB methods ?

Comment: Then it depends on who and how it injects the `EntityManager` instances. You can check whether it is the same transaction: persist&flush a new entity in one method and throw an exception in another. The result should be, that nothing is persisted.

Comment: I have one more question please, does the REQUIRED behaviour imply that in the case no transaction exsists yet, a new one will be created ?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly as you said. Details are here to every [`TransactionAttributeType`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/TransactionAttributeType.html#REQUIRED) :)